# Quick Sort. Handling Duplicates

Tags: java, sorting, duplicates, quicksort

Can someone show me how to handle duplicates in QuickSort with my function here?

```
private static int[] quickSort(int[] input, int left, int right) {
    int mid = (left + right) / 2;
    int i = left;
    int j = right;

    if((right - left) < 1) {
        return new int[]{};
    }

    while(i <= j) {
        while((input[i] < input[mid])) {
            i++;
        }

        while((input[j] > input[mid])) {
            j--;
        }

        if(i <= j) {
            int temp = input[i];
            input[i] = input[j];
            input[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    if(j > left) {
        input = quickSort(input, left, j);
    }

    if(i < right) {
        input = quickSort(input, i, right);
    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a simple example of where your code is not handling duplicates and what you would like it to do instead? e.g. if I try to sort `1, 1, 0, 3` it throws this exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code has several problems.

- "return new int[]{};" This will generate new arrays and consumes memory unnecessarily. You may return "input".
- For the first inner loops, you may want to have "input[i] <= input[mid] && i < mid". This will handle duplicates.

There are some well-tested code here: [Quick Sort](http://theoryapp.com/quick-sort/)